# Unable to deploy to Google App Engine using gcloud .netrc or any other method

Tags: git, google-app-engine

I can't deploy to Google App Engine anymore.

```
$ git init
$ gcloud auth login
$ git config credential.helper gcloud.sh
$ gcloud config set project <project-name>
$ git push google master

fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your OAuth token password; Note that generated google.com passwords 
are not compatible with private repositories
```

After some googling we find this text and a link on Google App Engine console.

```
Alternatively, instead of using the Google Cloud SDK to manage your authentication, you 
can manually generate your Git credentials by following this link.
```

We follow the link, generate git credentials and add it to our .netrc file. And voila.

```
$ git push google master

fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your OAuth token password; Note that generated google.com passwords 
are not compatible with private repositories
```

It still doesn't work. I have run out of ideas. I am using OSX.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question still gets views I will add an answer here. It looks like you were mixing the authentication methods for pushing to a [Google Code Repository](https://code.google.com/hosting/settings) with pushing to a [Google Cloud Source Repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/). Some of the details have been updated since this question was posted but in essence the older Google Code repos on https://code.google.com use a username and password which you can set in .netrc, and the newer Cloud Repos on https://console.cloud.google.com/code are tied to your Google Cloud Platform project and use OAuth for authentication via gcloud.sh.

Steps for connecting to a Google Cloud Source Repository:

```
$ git init local-repo
$ cd local-repo
$ git config credential.helper gcloud.sh
$ git remote add google https://source.developers.google.com/p/[PROJECT_ID]/r/default
$ git push google master
```

Steps for older repositories hosted on Google Code:

1) Retrieve credentials from https://code.google.com/hosting/settings
2) Edit .netrc:
    machine code.google.com login @google.com 
3)

```
$ git init local-repo
$ cd local-repo
$ git remote add google https://<project>.googlecode.com/git
$ git push google master
```